# Adding a C wire and fixing White vs Red on my Furnace

Tags: electrical, thermostat, furnace, thermostat-c-wire

TLDR: I think I need to flip R and W wires, and to splice the blue (C) wire to the brown wire coming of the transformer. Is this correct?

Long version:

Like many others on here, I'm trying to add a C wire to my thermostat, and to my furnace so that I can use a smarter thermostat.

The thermostat has the red and white wires connected to their respective R and W terminals.  The blue wire is present, but not connected.

According to my **understanding** of how thermostats are supposed to work, the R wire is supposed to be connected to 24v, while the W wire is energized only when the thermostat is calling for heat.

On my furnace, however, *P3-9*, the always-energized 24v wire, which is white, connects to T2, which is connected to the W terminal on the thermostat, and *P3-7*, the 'energized with heat wire' is red, but is connected to the R terminal.

**Shouldn't these be switched?**

Using battery power it doesn't matter, but I'm concerned that if I add a smart thermostat I'll need this to be correct.

Similarly, I believe that I can splice the Brown wire that goes from opposite the white wire on the transformer to *P2-2* to the terminal block and then to the B wire going to the thermostat.

**Is this correct?**

I've annotated the wiring diagram with what I think are the correct fixes.

[image: Lots of Wires][image: Wiring diagram edited]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only things you need is a tap from `Pink` to connect to the <kbd>B</kbd> common wire and to flip the `red` and `white` wires on the `Thermostat terminals:` block.

Write down a big <kbd>W</kbd> above the `T1 conn.` and <kbd>R</kbd> below the `T2 conn.` label so you or whoever has to look at it later doesn't get confused.

Comment: That agrees with my analysis as well, but the red/white thing seems a bit non-standard.  Guess nobody cared when this furnace came out.

Comment: Followed these directions and new thermostat is working